# Parse JSON's element name

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I just built an assessment application, and this is saved answer.

> {"2":"E","4":"C","5":"A"}

I meant the user just answered number 2, 4 and 5. Then I wanted to parse each answered in this format

> 1. Not answered
> 2. E
> 3. Not answered
> 4. C
> 5. A
> 6. Not answered

Any ideas how to parse it?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: what language are you working in?

Comment: The title doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question.

Comment: I've fixed it using jquery. I loop and print 'Not Answered' when it's undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var obj = {
    "2": "E",
    "4": "C",
    "5": "A"
};

for (var i = 1, size = 6; i <= size; i++) {
    console.log(i +'. '+ (obj[i] || 'Not answered'));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vrhTA/

Comment: thanks anyway. I've already fixed it. I looped trough the problems.length and print Not Answered when it's undefined